# Using mysql query to select record less than current date?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I want to select records from table which arrival_date is less than current date (arrival_date is field name in table honymoon_enquries table) date my code is

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    session_start();

    require_once("config.php");

    if($_SESSION["valid"] != true) 
    {   
        header("Location: index.php");

        exit(0);    
    }   

    if(count($_REQUEST['users']) > 0)   
    {
        //print_r($_REQUEST['users']);     
        $DeleteList = implode(",",$_REQUEST['users']);

        $UpdateQuery = " UPDATE honymoon_enquries SET deleted = '1' WHERE id IN (".$DeleteList.") ";

        mysql_query($UpdateQuery);    
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['pageid']) && $_REQUEST['pageid'] > 1)    
    {    
        $start = ($_REQUEST['pageid'] - 1) * 10;

        $pageidprev = $_REQUEST['pageid'] - 1;

        $pageidnext = $_REQUEST['pageid'] + 1;    
    }    
    else  
    {    
        $start = 0;

        $pageidprev = 1;

        $pageidnext = 2;   
    }

    $countquery = "SELECT count(*) AS counter FROM honymoon_enquries WHERE status='1' AND deleted = '0' ";


    $countres=mysql_query($countquery);

$count = mysql_fetch_array($countres);

    //print_r($count);

     $query = "select * from honymoon_enquries WHERE status='1' AND deleted = '0' order by arrival_date DESC LIMIT ".$start.",10 ";  // i want update this query

$res=mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($res) < 10)    
{   
        $pageidnext = $pageidnext-1;    
}    

if(($start+10) > $count['counter'])   
{  
    $end = $count['counter']; 
}  
else   
{ 
    $end = $start+10;   
}

$main .= "  
            <script>



            function DeleteUser()
            {
                if(confirm('Are you sure want to delete this contact?'))
                {
                    document.frm.submit();
                }
            }

            </script>

            <div class=heading>Manage Subscribers</div>

            $msg

            <form name='frm' method='post' action='users.php'>

            <table width=100%>

            <tr>

            <td colspan='6'><strong>Showing ".($start+1)." to ".$end." of ".$count['counter']."</strong></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

            <td colspan='6' align='left'>

            <a href='users.php?pageid=".$pageidprev."'>Prev</a>&nbsp;

            <a href='users.php?pageid=".$pageidnext."'>Next</a>

            </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

            <td><strong>Check</strong></td>

            <td><strong>Name</strong></td>

            <td><strong>Email</strong></td>

            <td><strong>Phone</strong></td>

            <td><strong>Arival Date</strong></td>

            <td><strong>Action</strong></td>

            </tr>

            ";



            while ($resresult=mysql_fetch_array($res))

        {
            //print_r($resresult);

            $main .= "

            <tr>

            <td><input type='checkbox' name='users[]' value='".$resresult['id']."' ></td>

            <td align='left'>".$resresult['client_name']."</td>

            <td align='left' >".$resresult['client_email']."</td>

            <td align='left' >".$resresult['client_phone']."</td>

            <td align='center' >".$resresult['arrival_date']."</td>

            <td align='center' ><a href='viewuser.php?pageid=".$resresult['id']."'>View User</a></td>

            </tr>

             ";
        }

        $main .= "<tr>

            <td colspan='6' align='left'>

            <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='DeleteUser();'>Delete</a>&nbsp;

            </td>

            </tr>";

            $main .= "

            </table>

            </form>

             ";

    $yescallme=1;

    $page = "users";

    require_once("includes/template.php");
    ?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your PHP code is not particularly useful here - much better is the table schema, and perhaps your attempt at a query.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM honymoon_enquries
WHERE arrival_date < NOW()
```

Comment: @shani inlove: what do you mean with _that's not working_? Which result do you have? Or which error? My query is OK, believe me. Tell us more, for example your table definition, result you get with my query and expected result. We will solve your trouble :)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW() in C:\wamp\www\data\newsletter\user2.php on line 88

Comment: i have modified query like....  $query = "SELECT * FROM honymoon_enquries
WHERE arrival_date <".NOW();

Comment: @shani inlove: `NOW()` is an internal MySql function, so you must use it inside your query: it must be processed by MySql, not by PHP. Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)